# Configuring .htaccess for React applications (+Router) inside a subdirectory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apache, .htaccess, react-router

I have a React application which is located in the `mysite.com/admin` directory. So `index.html` is located in `mysite.com/admin/index.html`. The application contains routes like `/admin/users` or `/admin/tools/removeUser`.

How do I configure `.htaccess` to load `mysite.com/admin/index.html` when I open `mysite.com/admin/` for exapmle? The url itself should remain the same in order to render necessary route.

Should say that there is also a React app in the root directory. Here is what I tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#for app in subdirectory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^admin admin/index.html [L]

#for root app
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

But when I open `mysite.com/admin/tools/removeUser` for example, in the console I get this error:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

You're right.

### Potential problem.

When run on local server Node JS routing (components are BrowserRouter, Switch, Route ) is work fine. Opening direct link and reload page correct work.
But when deploy on web server Apache are situation, start component app work (because page don’t reload), but when reload page then appear 404 page. The same page 404 appear when opening direct link contens a part of route app. Server Appache requires correct settings in file .httpaccess
For example I have two CMS on server apache and one of them is  SPA. Мy CMS should have rules and another system like SPA should have rules in .httpaccess

### Possible solutions:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    #for app in subdirectory
    RewriteBase /admin/
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule ^.*admin/.* /admin/index.html [L]
    #for root app
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

It is important that the rules for the application subdirectory do not overwrite the rules for the main application

Comment: Great answer! Works for me having a React Application running in a subfolder of a ReactJS/GatsbyJS website. Small comment: First line should be `RewriteEngine on`

Comment: Thank you. fixed on RewriteEngine on